# How can I have PHP avoid lazy evaluation?

Tags: php, function, lazy-evaluation, boolean-logic

I have an interesting question about the way PHP evaluates boolean expressions.   When you have, for example,

```
$expression = $expression1 and $expression2;
```

or

```
if ($expression1 and $expression2)
```

PHP first checks if `$expression1` evaluates to **`true`**. If this is not the case, then `$expression2` is simply skipped to avoid unnecessary calculations.  In a script I am writing, I have:

```
if ($validator->valid("title") and $validator->valid("text"))
```

I need to have the second statement (`$validator->valid("text")`) evaluated even if the first one evaluates to false.  I would like to ask you whether there is some easy way to force PHP to always evaluate both statements. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is known as [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), and to avoid it you need to do this, using a single `&`:

```
if($validator->valid("title") & $validator->valid("text")) {

}
```

Note that this is not using [logical operators](http://www.php.net/language.operators.logical) but actually [bitwise operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php):

> They're operators that act on the binary representations of numbers. They do not take logical values (i.e., "true" or "false") as arguments without first converting them to the numbers 1 and 0 respectively. Nor do they return logical values, but numbers. Sure, you can later treat those numbers as though they were logical values (in which case 0 is cast to "false" and anything else is cast to "true"), but that's a consequence of PHP's type casting rules, and nothing to do with the behavior of the operators.

As such, there is *some* debate as to whether it is good practice to use this side effect to circumvent short-circuit evaluation. I would personally at least put a comment that the & is intentional, but if you want to be as pure as possible you should evaluate whether they are valid first and then do the if.

Comment: This is very unwise. What if the first one returns true, and the latter returns 2. true&2 make false! In addition, a maintainer will likely come along and say "whoops, that should be &&, not &", breaking the code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710919/how-can-i-have-php-avoid-lazy-evaluation/710936#710936 is a much safer and clearer answer.

Comment: I am perfectly aware of the limitations, did you even read my answer?

Comment: @Paolo Bergantino: I did. I wanted to point out that this shouldn't be chosen as the correct answer, clever as it is (well, its too clever really).

Comment: personally I think this is *very* clever and I think there are plllllllenty of PHP users out there who go 'what if the second argument is an uninstantiated object' I voted this up because it's actually illegal in Australia to use '&' and '^' in any "code snippet that you just chuck in because you know what it does, not how it does it" i.e. bitwise operators aren't f0re n00bs

Comment: lol... I came looking for confirmation that PHP is lazy, I left starting an elegance discussion - I <3 the internet

Comment: I think it would be much cleaner solution if you casted the stuff into boolean, like `if( (bool)$v->valid('title') & (bool)$v->valid('text') )`, otherwise the '&' operator doesn't behave as expected, as Paul Biggar mentioned.

Comment: Bitwise operation also interferes with `var_export()`. E.g., `var_export(true & false)` returns a different result than `var_export(true && false)`.

Answer (score 28):

```
$isValidTitle = $validator->valid("title");
$isValidText = $validator->valid("text");
if($isValidTitle && $isValidText)
{
    ...
}
```

Will that suit?

Comment: I like this solution because it's explicitly stated that the methods should be executed as code, not as a simple test.  There are schools of thought that believe statements with side effects should never go into control statements - control statements are only for testing, never executing.

Answer (score 4):

try to evaluate each term separately:

```
$term1 = $validator->valid("title");
$term2 = $validator->valid("text");
if($term1 && $term2) {
//things to do
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the best implementation, but you could always do:

```
$a=$validator->valid("title");
$b=$validator->valid("text");
if($a && $b) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function like:

```
function logical_and($x,$y) {return ($x && $y);}
```

Since PHP uses call-by-value, this works.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you can modify the class $validator instantiates, you could make the valid method accept a string or an array.  If it's an array, it runs the code that already exists on each item and only returns TRUE if all items are "valid".