# Use logical operator if either method result or variable is set

Tags: php, codeigniter

Using Codeigniter I want to check if form validation is false or if my other variable is set:

```
if (isset($answer_error) || $this->form_validation->run() == false)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

But for some reason I can't check both in one conditional statement, why is that?

EDIT: What was I dealing with is called a "short circuit evaluation" [How can I have PHP avoid lazy evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710919/how-can-i-have-php-avoid-lazy-evaluation)

Fixed it by first evaluationg each term

```
$validation = $this->form_validation->run();
$my_validation = isset($answer_error);

if ($my_validation || $validation == false) 
{}
```

Comment: Use `&&` operator instead if `||` to check both in one condition!!

Comment: I need to check if either is set not both

Comment: It DOES do what you're asking for. Perhaps you're not phrasing the question properly ... I suspect that by "is set" you might mean "is not empty", which is a different thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `|` operator instead. This will set the condition, while still cheking the rest of the instructions

Comment: isn't this operator used for comparing bits?

Comment: Yes it is. However, in PHP whenever a `true` condition happens in an `ìf` statement happens, there is no need to check for the rest of it (Java behaves like this as well). In order for all conditions to be check, you might want to do an bit operation, or put "context" `(($validation || $othervalidation)==true)` or calculate the full operator first. ([btw this is the link for documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php))

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (isset($answer_error) or $this->form_validation->run() == false)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```